# JavaScript - Is there a way to find out whether the given characters are contained in a string without looping?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, algorithm

I have an array of combinations from 5 characters (order within a combination plays no role):

AB, ABDE, CDE, C, BE ...

On its basis I need to validate the input from user. The entered combination of characters should be contained in one of the combinations of the array.
If user enters "ADE" or "CE" the result should be `yes`, if e.g. "BCE" - `no`.

In a trivial case, when entered combination simply matches the one in array, I can use `.inArray`. If entered combination consists of neighbors, I can do `.indexOf`. How to be in the case above?
One of the solutions would be to extend the initial array by including all possible "child" combinations. Is there an alternative?

Comment: Not certain what the logic is? What is the expected result for "when entered combination simply matches the one in array"

Comment: If the entered combination is in array, the result is positive, the input is validated, yes. This is what I call a trivial case.

Comment: Do you mean if `"AB"` and `"D"` are input the result should be `yes`? As one match is found in array? It is not clear what expected input, matching logic or result is. Can you include the code that you have tried to resolve inquiry at Question? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Have you got anything like `set difference` or bit/binary operation AND in your language/framework?

Comment: Yes. But even if "AB" were not in array, the answer should anyway be yes, since AB is contained in ABDE, but this is again trivial since A and B are neighbors and this can be checked by indexOf.

Comment: @Mbo It would be perfect to have it as a jQuery.

Comment: Can your sets only contain the same 5 elements? Why not convert them to bitmasks, so that your example is [00011, 11011, 11100, 00100, 10010], which is [3, 27, 28, 4, 18]. Do the same for the input. A set `s` contains all elements of the in put `x` when `(s & x) == x`. (The conversion is a loop, of course, but that has to be done only once per set.)

Comment: You can use your input as a regular expression, inserting `.*` after each character, so: `var regex = '.*' + inputStr.split('').join('.*') + '.*';` and then match it to combinations from your array. But I like what @MOehm suggested more.

Comment: @MOehm Perfect! This is very nice solution, exactly what is needed. Yes, I always have the same 5 characters. 0101 & 0001 gives 0001 as result, right? And this operator is available in jQuery? Any good ref to effective conversion to bitmasks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing I could think of is grep'ping the array with a regex match.

```js
var haystack = ["BCED","DBCE","CEB","ECBA","CB","BDCA"];
var needle = "CBE";
var re = new RegExp("(?=.*" + needle.split('').join(")(?=.*") + ").{" + needle.length+"}");
console.log(re);
console.log($.grep(haystack, function(str){
   return str.match(re,"g");
}));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll expand on the comment I've made to the quesion above: If you have a small number of fixed set elements, you can represent the sets as binary masks. So say you have the original sets as strings:

```
var sset = ["AB", "ABDE", "CDE", "C", "BE"];
```

Create a dictionary of possible elements and bits. The bits are powers of two, which can be created by bit-shifting: `1 << n` is bit `n`:

```
dict = {
    A: (1 << 0),
    B: (1 << 1),
    C: (1 << 2),
    D: (1 << 3),
    E: (1 << 4),
};
```

That dictionary can then be used to create the bitmask:

```
function bitmask(s, d) {
    let res = 0;

    for (let i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
        res |= d[s[i]]
    }

    return res;
}
```

Create a companion array to the sets that contains the masks:

```
var mset = sset.map(function(x) { return bitmask(x, dict); });
```

If you want to check an input, cnvert it to a mask first and then run the checks. A set `s` contains all bits of an input `x` if `(s & x) == x`:

```
var s = "ADE";
var m = bitmask(s, dict);
for (let i = 0; i < mset.length; i++) {
    console.log(sset[i], s, (mset[i] & m) == m);
}
```

You can use this strategy for several conditions:

• `(a & b) == b` — all elements of `b` are contained in `a`;
• `(a & b) == 0` — `a` and `b` have no common elements;
• `(a & b) != 0` — at least one elements of `b` is in `a`;
• `a == b` — the sets `a` and `b` are identical.

In set parlance `a & b` is the intersection, `a | b` is the union and `a ^ b` is the symmetric difference of `a` and `b`.

As far as I know, jQuery is a library written in Javascript, so all bit-wise operators should be available.